# Check if a class in javascript exists

Tags: javascript, class, defined

Working on [MDN classes concept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class), I'd like to check if a class exits (not object nor function) in order to load it dynamically and redefine it if it is.

I tried many way (typeOf, instanceof...) unsuccessfully ...

```
    Class APP{
[...]
    registerModule( moduleName, force ) 
    {
        if( this.modules[ moduleName ] === undefined || force )
        {
console.log( "loading "+moduleName+"/js/"+moduleName+"Module.js ..." );
            //~ TODO : Add a test if class already loaded and if we have to 'unload' or re-define it
            this.loadScript( moduleName+"/js/"+moduleName+"Module.js", function(){
                APP.modules[moduleName] = eval( "new "+moduleName+"()" );
            });
        }else{
            alert( "Moule '"+moduleName+"' already declared !");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A class _is_ a function. So `typeof SomeClass === "function"` would be the first step.

Comment: How may you *not* know whether a class is defined? You need to get a handle on the class first, typically these days through `import Foo from 'bar'` or something along those lines. In that case you can be pretty sure the class exists. I'd hope you're not important something of which you have no idea what it is.

Comment: Can we see what you tried?

Comment: If your classes are actually defined as `class Foo {}`, then you cannot even attempt to load the same class twice, it will result in an error. So "unloading" a class won't work.

Comment: That's my problem !

Comment: Why may you be getting into a situation in which you're loading a class a second time?!

Comment: My APP loads modules when a user choose this module (button) but the module can already be loaded.
Reloading it can be usefull if it has been updated

Comment: Then your loader should keep track of what it has already loaded and not attempt to load it a second time.

Comment: This notation was introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)
Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a way :

```
class APP{
    constructor() {
        this.modules = [];
    }

    registerModule( moduleName, force ) 
    {
        if( this.modules[ moduleName ] === undefined || force )
        {
            if( this.modules[ moduleName ] === undefined )
            {
                this.loadScript( moduleName+"/js/"+moduleName+"Module.js", function(){
                    APP.modules[moduleName] = eval( "new "+moduleName+"()" );
                });
            }else{
                    APP.modules[moduleName] = eval( "new "+moduleName+"()" );
            }
        }else{
            alert( "Le module '"+moduleName+"' est déjà déclaré !");
        }
    }
}
```

Can be called this way :

```
APP.registerModule( 'Batch' ,true)
```

Class is instanciated at first load.
Object is overwritten on new module registration, based on the same class definition. Class cannot be redefined (too bad).
Thanks for your comments !